# All my objects are rotating together when I try to rotate them individually

Tags: modeling

I don't know what I pressed or set on accident but now every time I try to rotate any object separately, multiple objects are moving together. I first noticed it with my camera, trying to rotate it. I tried deleting the camera, restarting Blender, and researching anything I could for "locked/paired/pinned objects while rotating" with no luck. I'm sure this is a quick and easy thing, I just have no clue what the issue is to find/fix. Thanks! Video demo below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F70-PfBPZAI

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is proportional editing turned on? The shortcut for it is "O" on the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much.